# Python Selenium how to click all classes found in new tabs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently trying to open each mod tile from nexus mods one by one into individual tabs and download the files. Currently I have

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='mod-image']")
for element in element:
  element.click()
```

How would I open half of the tiles in a new tab and then the other half later? (Using chrome)

Comment: Using a range 0 from to len(element)/2 would do the first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Python much but the JAVA code looks like-

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='mod-image']"));
for(WebElement e : elements) {
    e.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just have to convert this over to python then